# Changing color of image embedded to a button (Swift3)

Tags: ios, uiimageview, uibutton, swift3, mask

I am able to change the color of an image of a `UIButton` from black to white with the following code:

```
extension UIImage {
    func maskWith(color: UIColor) -> UIImage {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, false, scale)

        let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!
        context.translateBy(x: 0, y: size.height)
        context.scaleBy(x: 1.0, y: -1.0)
        context.setBlendMode(.normal)

        let rect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: size.width, height: size.height)
        context.clip(to: rect, mask: cgImage!)

        color.setFill()
        context.fill(rect)

        let newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()!

        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    return newImage
    }
}
```

I am setting the color of the image of the `UIButton` using the following:

```
//creditCardBtn is the the button variable
creditCardBtn.imageView?.image? = (creditCardBtn.imageView?.image?.maskWith(color: .white))!
```

**My Issue**
When the user sets their finger on the button and then slowly drags their finger away, the image color resets itself. My thought was to use an `@IBAction` and reset the `UIButton`'s image when there is a `Touch Up Inside`. However this did not prevent the image from resetting its color.

Here is the code I tried:

```
@IBAction func creditCardTap(_ sender: UIButton) {
    creditCardBtn.imageView?.image?.maskWith(color: .white)
}
```

**What I am looking for:**
How to prevent the button from resetting its color from UI activities.

Comment: Have you tried experimenting with other action events on the button?  Perhaps Touch Down, Touch Drag Exit, or Touch Cancel?

Comment: I just tried `Did End On Exit`, `Touch Cancel`, `Touch Down`, `Touch Drag Exit`, and `Touch Up Inside`. The color is still changing when the user has UI activities.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's a simpler way to do this without any extension and without resetting the color on touch:

```
let stencil = myImage.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate) // use your UIImage here
myButton.setImage(stencil, for: .normal) // assign it to your UIButton
myButton.tintColor = UIColor.white // set a color
```

Comment: +1 for making the code much more simple and eliminating the need for the extention and then another +1 for providing a solution that avoided me having to reset the color on UI events. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this it's working for me.

```
let image = UIImage(named: "menu")
    let tintedImage = image?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)
    mapMenuButton.setImage(tintedImage, for: .normal)
    mapMenuButton.tintColor = UIColor.appThemeColor()
```

Answer (score 1):

**swift 4 and 4.2**

```
let img = UIImage.init(named: "buttonName")?.withRenderingMode(UIImageRenderingMode.alwaysTemplate)
            btn.setImage(img, for: .normal)
            btn.tintColor = .gray

}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
  //works in func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt IndexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell

if redButton == true {
        let stencil = UIImage(named: "phoneCircle.png")?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)
        cell.patientCTCallButton.setImage(stencil, for: .normal)
        cell.patientCTCallButton.tintColor = .red // set a color
}
```

[image: white "phoneCircle.png" before colored red]
[image]