# How can I change a group of button's image's colors in Swift3?

Tags: ios, uiimageview, uibutton, swift3, rendering

I recently asked a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41352576/changing-color-of-image-embedded-to-a-button-swift3) where I wanted to understand how to change the `UIColor` of a `button`'s `image`. I followed @Dorian Roy's recommendation which was very clean and it worked well for my needs. While my specific question previously was around a single button, I would like to know how to change multiple `UIBUttons`. Can this be done? My thought would be to `subclass` a `UIButton` and initialize it to automatically change its `image` color. I can't quite grasp how to do this though.

Here is how I am currently performing this action and I am seeking a more elegant solution.

```
private func changeBtnColors() {
    let ccStencil = creditCardBtn.imageView?.image?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)
    let planeStencil = planeBtn.imageView?.image?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)
    let towelStencil = towelBtn.imageView?.image?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)
    let carStencil = carBtn.imageView?.image?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)
    let trainStencil = trainBtn.imageView?.image?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)
    let graphStencil = graphBtn.imageView?.image?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)

    creditCardBtn.setImage(ccStencil, for: .normal)
    planeBtn.setImage(planeStencil, for: .normal)
    towelBtn.setImage(towelStencil, for: .normal)
    carBtn.setImage(carStencil, for: .normal)
    trainBtn.setImage(trainStencil, for: .normal)
    graphBtn.setImage(graphStencil, for: .normal)

    creditCardBtn.tintColor = UIColor.white
    planeBtn.tintColor = UIColor.white
    towelBtn.tintColor = UIColor.white
    carBtn.tintColor = UIColor.white
    trainBtn.tintColor = UIColor.white
    graphBtn.tintColor = UIColor.white
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest way is create one array of `UIButton` and loop through all the elements.

```
let buttonArray = [creditCardBtn, planeBtn, towelBtn, carBtn, trainBtn, graphBtn]
buttonArray.forEach { button in
    let image = button.imageView?.image?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)
    button.setImage(image, for: .normal)
    button.tintColor = UIColor.white
}
```

You can also create `extension` of `UIButton` and put this settings code of `Button` in a function like this.

```
extension UIButton {
    func setImageWithRandringMode() {
        let image = self.imageView?.image?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)
        self.setImage(image, for: .normal)
        self.tintColor = .white
    }
}
```

And now simply call this function with `forEach` closure.

```
buttonArray.forEach { button in

    button.setImageWithRandringMode()
}
```